# Show/hide button using ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a problem related to the visibility of a button. I have to hide a button when there is no text in the form field, and show it back when it's filled. I've got some code:

```
    <div class="TextAreaCont">
        <input ng-model="pageUrl" placeholder="Facebook Page URL" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="ButtonCont" ng-show="ctrl.isButtonVisible()">
        <button ng-click="ctrl.send()">Fetch data</button>
    </div>
```

And I wrote it:

```
Facebook.controller('PageCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.isButtonVisible = function(){
    if($scope.pageUrl){return true}else{return false}
};
```

Where is the problem?
To be honest, I've never leart JS and Angular.

Comment: What is wrong? Is it always visible? Never visible? Please clarify your question

Comment: It's always visible now. I'd like to do visible only when there will be any text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zrXKOYEeQ6ouRh7Ylsnl?p=preview) is my solution

```
var Facebook = angular.module('Facebook', []);

Facebook.controller('PageCtrl', [function(){

  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.isButtonVisible = function(){
    if(ctrl.pageUrl){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  };

  ctrl.send = function(){
    console.log('Page URL: ' + ctrl.pageUrl)
  };
}]);
```

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zrXKOYEeQ6ouRh7Ylsnl?p=preview) for more details.

Few problems that I can spot in your original code:

- when using `controller as` syntax, use 'this' keyword, not `$scope` inside your controller
- `ng-model="pageUrl"` should be `ng-model="ctrl.pageUrl"`

Just FYI, `isButtonVisible()` will be evaluated on every digest cycle, so there no need for watchers of `ng-change`.

Comment: Or, more succinctly, `return !!ctrl.pageUrl;`.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan I agree, there is no limit for perfection :) I would use regex to validate if URL is valid `return /^((https?):\/\/)?([w|W]{3}\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{3,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?$/.test(ctrl.pageUrl);`

Answer (score 0):

try this.
i put simple example.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.display = false;
      $scope.isButtonVisible = function(pageUrl){     
    if(pageUrl){
      $scope.display = true;
      }
     else{$scope.display = false;}
};
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  
   <input ng-model="pageUrl" placeholder="Facebook Page URL" type="text" ng-change="isButtonVisible(pageUrl)">
 <div class="ButtonCont" ng-show="display">
        <button ng-click="send()">Fetch data</button>
    </div>
  
  <input ng-model="pageUrl2" placeholder="Facebook Page URL" type="text" ng-change="isButtonVisible(pageUrl)">
 <div class="ButtonCont" ng-show="pageUrl2">
        <button ng-click="send()">Fetch data</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. :) But what should i do if i'd like to do it as a function in other file?

Comment: Or, more succinctly, `$scope.display = !!pageUrl;`.

Comment: @ Mike McCaughan yes it is nice:)

Comment: @hadiJZ Oh, yes, I've just noticed it. :/